# Do Judy and Peter remember anything from the events in Jumanji?

Tags: timeline, jumanji

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17908/19561), the game Jumanji teaches its players important life lessons.

> Jumanji appears to be an artifact designed to teach the players important values, as games often do, but with a far more sensory-immersion effect. Considering when the game ends, the lessons learned are lasting moral ones, learned under realistic conditions with examples of the consequences of actions fully displayed.

Not just Sarah and Alan play the game, but Judy and Peter as well. However, after finishing the game, we see the timeline reset to the moment where Sarah and Alan started playing. The movie then ends 26 years into the future of a *new* timeline, where the Parrish shoe factory has remained successful (or grown even more so), and where Alan and Sarah are married and about to meet a new employee, his wife, and their two kids: Judy and Peter. Sarah and Alan of course recognise them, but do Judy and Peter recognise Sarah and Alan in turn?
And are Sarah and Alan the only ones who learned anything from playing Jumanji, or have Judy and Peter learned important lessons as well (like not cheating) in turn for their troubles?

Do Judy and Peter remember anything from the events in Jumanji, from a game they haven't played in the new timeline?

Comment: Maybe the "original" Judy and Peter were actually part of Jumanji illusion too! Could Jumanji have created an entire illusory world after Sarah and Alan started playing? It did create the jungle, after all.

Comment: @KSmarts oh god ... my brain

Comment: @MacCooper Unfortunately, no one can be told what Jumanji is. You have to see it for yourself.

Comment: @KSmarts - Rule #1 of Jumanji, no-one mentions the sequel.

Comment: Wellp, _Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle_ either worked differently or the two current answers are definitely wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No; Peter and Judy do *not* remember the events of the movie, as they do not remember Sarah and Allen.

As previously mentioned, there is a clear distinction between the surprise of Sarah and Allen, who remember the events and recognise the children, to the unresponsiveness of Peter and Judy, who do not remember the events nor Sarah and Allen.

Furthermore, the children to react with confusion, when Allen says that they are 'just as he remembers them'. This feels especially conclusive; had the children remembered the events, they might still pretend to be meeting Sarah and Allen for the first time, but they would *not* be confused by the two recognising them.

Answer (score 8):

No.

There's no sign or emotion from either of them that shows they're saying anything other than a respected hello to friend of their folks.  So they don't remember.

This isn't too surprising, as they had quite a bit of their history rewritten by Sarah and Allen remembering, and preventing, their parents deaths.  I like to think they get very vivid dreams later, and clue in, but nothing like that is actually shown.

Comment: I always had the feeling they showed emotions that they remember Sarah and Alan. Especially when the yell NO! to the idea of the trip of the parents, the kids are smiling. This always bothered me, because if they knew their parents were gonna die on that trip, why woudn't they try to prevent the parents to go. But this is the usual paradox of time travel..

Comment: @Thomas - actually, if this was before the ski trip, and therefore before the time when they even would have touched the game, they'd have to be remembering the future at this point.  So I don't buy that they know there.

Comment: It would be fun if they did remember, and that's what I always thought as a kid. But their smile doesn't have to mean they remember their parents died/would die. Judy expressed sadness earlier/later/(alternatively?) that their parents didn't ever have time for them, so of course they'd be happy to have their parents' trip cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

As above answers have said, Peter and Judy definitely did not seem to remember at the point in time when they meet Alan and Sarah for the first time.

However, this is not proof of them never remembering. In the original movie timeline where Alan went missing, Judy and Peter find and play the game a few months after their parents went on a ski trip and died.

In the new timeline where Alan & Sarah are married, they haven't reached that point in time yet. Since Alan and Sarah knew how Peter and Judy's parents died, they sought to deliberately change that by: 
a) finding and hiring them to work for them, 
b) getting them to *not* go on that fateful ski trip.

Either way, when Judy and Peter meet Alan and Sarah for the first time in the new timeline, their parents are *planning* to go for that ski trip where they would have eventually died. So Peter and Judy are still a few months away from the point in the original timeline when they played the game.

The new movie shows events where the missing person from the original timeline (Alex) returns home but seems to have deliberately not sought out the other players or attempted to change their lives. As such, the events which lead to all of them getting detention still happen. However here comes the interesting speculation and paradox part, which means that it's not completely out of imagination that Peter and Judy may eventually regain their memories of the game.

In Jumanji 2 - the Original Timeline (J2OT) -

1. Alex plays the game as the pilot - 'taking up' that PC slot - and goes
   missing, creating the existence of the 'Freak House' tragedy.
2. Alex's parents donate his video game stuff to the school? where it eventually ends up in the storage.
3. Spencer, Fridge, Martha and Bethany (SFMB) grow up with the 'Freak House' and knowledge of the tragedy of Alex Reek
4. SFMB get detention and find the game in the storage and decide to
   play.
5. SFMB try to pick the pilot character and find it locked.
   Hence they pick the 4 remaining characters.
6. Jumanji!

At this point, Alex is able to return to his starting point, creating a new timeline branching out from 1996 (J2NT) and where all the paradoxes start.

1. Alex returns home, hence no 'Freak House' tragedy. He grows up into an adult, marries, has kids.
2. Alex either destroys Jumanji or he doesn't. Honestly, it would be very weird for anyone if he didn't, but since we didn't see it, we don't know.
3. SFMB are born and grow up in a town without 'Freak House'.
4. SFMB get detention and viola! **The game is STILL waiting for them in the school storage area.** How? Even if Alex didn't destroy it, donating it to a school seems highly irresponsible and it's not like he ever knew that SFMB were playing this game in detention.
5. Was the **pilot character still locked**? If not why didn't Fridge select that like he originally wanted to do? And if it was, then how?
6. Jumanji!

And now SFMB walk down the road, expecting to see the Freak House. So post-Jumanji, **they now no longer have the memories of growing up in the new timeline, their NT memories have now all been replaced by OT memories.** In fact, they have OT memories even during the Jumanji game. One could say that they are actually **in** the OT while playing the game because clearly they only play the game with Alex.

It looks like Alex never tried to find the kids - and fair he only seems to know Spencer's full name. But since SFMB don't actually have any memories of their lives before Jumanji in the new timeline, we don't actually know for sure! For all we know, since they all seem to live in the same school district, Alex might very well be friends with some of the parents, and has spent the last however many years or months 'knowing' SFMB, while they were unaware about him or Jumanji, and he's reintroducing himself because he can see that for them all that stuff has just happened.

So! **Given that in Jumanji 2, despite all the paradox, the new kids still end up playing the game and 'get back' their OT memories, but only at the right time, it's highly possible that the same could happen to Peter and Judy a few months down the line after the end of the original movie.**

Of course, one possible difference is that in Jumanji, we know that Alan and Sarah have used their future knowledge to influence the new timeline in ways that directly affect Peter and Judy. However, we do not know for sure that this wasn't the case in Jumanji 2, too.

After all, despite their parents being alive, Peter and Judy have still moved to town. For all we know, a few months after that Christmas, they will end up finding the game somehow and 'play it' in the OT, and when they finish it, their NT memories of the past few months - with their parents being alive and employees of Alan and Sarah will have been replaced by the OT memories of their death and the events of the movie.

(And it is at this point in 1995 that they again throw the game away, leading it to be found by Alex's father in 1996)

Answer (score 0):

Judy and Peter DO remember Alan and Sarah just not yet. This can be easily explained. With the logic seen in Jumanji 2 the teenagers do remember the game and so does kid from '96. How does that work? Well, at the end of the first movie Alan and Sarah meet Judy and Peter BEFORE they played the game in 1995. (Meaning Dec 1994) And since the teens come back as they were in 2017 with only memories of the 'old timeline', the Judy and Peter from 1995 will not come back from Jumanji until 1995. In conclusion, Judy and Peter will recognize Alan and Sarah when 1995 rolls around, and not before like at the end of the first film in Christmas of '94.

Comment: What are you basing this on?

Comment: @Valorum this is the only way it could work based on the 2nd movie, all players remember but don't get the memories until the year they started playing. Otherwise Judy and Peter would have to be born with memories which they aren't. The 2nd movie everyone remembers so the only way to resolve this is they don't get the memories until they get older (the month they played), they just don't have them yet

Answer (score 0):

I would like to input that I do believe that Judy and Peter recognized Alan and Sarah as a way of deja vu. When the kids see the adults, there’s a quick flash of remembrance on Judy’s face. Like others have said, I don’t believe they remember Jumanji, but, their past lives recognize the adults.

Another interesting thing I’d noticed though was how they altered the timeline by preventing their parents from being killed. And Judy herself died right before Alan finished the game (after being barbed by the flower) so, it’s highly possible that those three would die in other means

Answer (score -1):

If your going off the logic of the new movie Jumanji(2017)
Then yes they would remember, because all characters in that movie despite being part of different time periods remember. I like to believe either way that they eventually remember what happens after they meet them again and that it jogs something in their mind to give them the memories.

Comment: What in the 2017 movie's logic gives the impression that they would remember? Can you back up your claim with any quotes or scene recaps from the movie?

Comment: @tobiasvl Because they all remember and rush to the previously run down house to see if they can find their new friend where they meet the now-older friend and they all obviously remember the entire adventure.  However this doesn't prove that the the same thing happens in the first movie, as the ending of that one shows no sign of the two younger players recognizing the two older or even remembering having the adventure, and they may not have had the adventure because timey-wimey.