# How did Sarah and Alan meet Judy and Peter’s parents?

Tags: jumanji

At the end of Jumanji, we see Sarah and Alan talking at a party with Mr. and Mrs. Shepard. The two introduce Sarah and Alan to their children, Judy and Peter.

Since [Judy and Peter don’t remember the events of Jumanji](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77195/79413), they only meet Sarah and Alan after being introduced by their parents, who seem to be close friends with each other.

How do Sarah and Alan know Judy and Peter’s parents? How did their families meet if Jumanji never happened?

Comment: That's explained in the question you've linked to: Judy and Peter's father is Alan's new employee.  It is implied (in the same scene, shown in the accepted answer) that Sarah and Alan deliberately sought him out in order to meet Judy and Peter again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Judy and Peter remember anything from the events in Jumanji?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77195/do-judy-and-peter-remember-anything-from-the-events-in-jumanji)

Comment: @Gothamite24 I'm unclear what makes this a duplicate. I'm asking how Sarah and Alan meet Judy and Peter's parents.